# Custom punctuation function making script run over the php's 60s runtime limit

Tags: php

I am importing allot of product data from an XML file (about 5000 products).
When I run the script I can make it work in about 10-12 seconds.

Now, when I add this punctuation function which makes sure each product description ends with a punctuation sign, the code runs until the php 60 seconds loadtime on my server but I'm not getting any errors.
I have error reporting turned on.
I just get a final error that the script could not load in 60 seconds.

**The question is, looking at this function, is it that resource consuming? What can I do to make it faster?**

Upon comments, the problem could be the pregmatch loop. Let me explain what this function does.
It check if the last character of the string is an punctuation mark.
If it's not, it matches the last char and checks again.

```
function punctuation($string){
    if(strlen($string) > 5){
        // Get $last_char
        $desired_punctuation = array(".",",","?","!");
        $last_char = substr($string, -1); 
        // Check if $last_char is in the $desired_punctuation array
        if(!in_array($last_char, $desired_punctuation)){ 
        // strip the $mytrim string and get only letters at the end;
            while(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $last_char)){
                $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
                $last_char = substr($string, -1);
            }
            // add "." to the string
            $string .= '.'; 
        } 
    }
    return $string;
}
```

If the function is ok, the long runtime must come from something else which I'll have to discover.

I just want your input on this part.

Comment: What's the main purpose of this function? Maybe there's a better way of doing it. Might be the `preg_match` loop over there. BTW , you can always `ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); // 1 hour` to set a higher execution time.

Comment: I did change it - whats weird is that 1 out of 5 tries it runs the script, the other 4 doesn't finish it - loading till error (this is on average). Btw Ofir, if no one else answer you should do it.

Comment: If you don't use this function , and use a function that just prints the product title , it will behave the same? Maybe the problem is in the process of loading those xml files...

Comment: Everything works until I use this function:)

Comment: Ok , what's the purpose of this function again? Why you need that `preg_match` loop? (If you can include the answer in your question above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to replace the while loop with a single `preg_replace()`

```
function punctuation($string){
  if(strlen($string) > 5){
    // Get $last_char
    $desired_punctuation = array(".",",","?","!");
    $last_char = substr($string, -1); 
    // Check if $last_char is in the $desired_punctuation array
    if(!in_array($last_char, $desired_punctuation)){ 
      // remove any trailing non-word characters, and add a period
      $string = preg_replace("/[\W]*$/", '.', $string);
    } 
  }
  return $string;
}
```

It would have to be tested if a `preg_match()` could also be faster than `in_array()`

```
function punctuation($string){
  if(strlen($string) > 5){
    // Check if the last character is a desired punctuation character
    if(!preg_match("/[.,?!]$/", $string)){ 
      // remove any trailing non-word characters, and add a period
      $string = preg_replace("/[\W]*$/", '.', $string);
    } 
  }
  return $string;
}
```

---

To get more detailed information on the run time of your code, including which functions are taking a long time and how often they are called, you should look into the [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) extensions.